# How to filter out with lquery?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, ltree

I'm using `LQUERY` to do some custom filtering in queries from my PostgreSQL -database. One of the fields is a `ltree` -field called `path` and I should be able to check which objects have a certain string in their `path` and filter them out.

I've tried this:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.ltree import LQUERY
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

custom_lquery = '!res_1.*'
stmnt = stmnt.filter(MyModel.path.lquery(expression.cast(custom_lquery, LQUERY)))
```

This filters out correctly objects which `path` starts with `res_1`. What I want to do, is to filter out all objects that have the `res_1` in any point of their `path`, e.g. `res_0.res_1.res_2`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Invert the filter.  I do not do ORMs, but the logic would be to have SQLAlchemy NOT the result of searching for `'*.res_1.*'`

Comment: @MikeOrganek That is what I try to do with the `!`..

Comment: I understand that, but I could not get the negation to work inside of the lquery.  It looks like that is not possible:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#:~:text=and%20you%20can%20put%20!%20(NOT)%20at%20the%20start%20of%20a%20non%2Dstar%20group%20to%20match%20any%20label%20that%20doesn%27t%20match%20any%20of%20the%20alternatives.  It has to be followed by a `non-star group`.

Comment: SQLAlchemy's shorthand for `not` is `~`, not `!`.  See [conjunctions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was achieved with the SQLAlchemy `not_`.

```
from sqlalchemy import not_

custom_lquery = '*.res_1.*'
stmnt = stmnt.filter(not_(MyModel.path.lquery(expression.cast(custom_lquery, LQUERY))))
```

Comment: Can also use the `~` operator which is doing exactly the same, but a bit less verbose: `stmnt.filter(~MyModel.path.lquery(expression.cast(custom_lquery, LQUERY)))`